# Why Mongoose sort is slower than native javascript sort?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I'm using Node.js 6.10.0 and Mongoose 4.8.5. Actually I'm trying to find the nearest coordinates from a coordinate and with a certain datetime. I have billions data into my MongoDB. I want to apply a sort to my query because I want to order by the datetime

(2017-03-02T03:**00:00.000**Z, 2017-03-02T03:**01:00.000**Z **...** 2017-03-02T03:**23:00.000**Z)

So here is my query with Mongoose sort:

```
var condition = {
    $nearSphere: {
       $geometry: {
          type : "Point",
          coordinates : [2.2871244564, 47.930476456445]
       }
   }
};

var date_condition = {
   $gte: new Date('2017-03-02'),
   $lt: new Date('2017-03-03')
};

var selected_fields = '-_id loc datetime';

console.time('find')
var query = Model.find({loc: condition, datetime: date_condition}, selected_fields)
                 .limit(24)
                 .sort({date: 'asc'})
                 .exec();

query.then(function(docs){
    var json = {};
    json.data = docs;
    console.timeEnd('find')
    res.json(json);
});
```

Here easy the same query with native sort :

```
console.time('find')
var query = Model.find({loc: condition, datetime: date_condition}, selected_fields)
                 .limit(24)
                 .exec();

query.then(function(docs){
    var json = {};
    docs.sort(function(a, b) {
        return new Date(a.datetime) - new Date(b.datetime);
    });
    json.data = docs;
    console.timeEnd('find')
    res.json(json);
});
```

Then with the Mongoose sort the request takes **8000 - 10000 MS**.
And with the native sort the request takes just **15 MS**.

Could you tell me why the native sort is better than Mongoose sort ? Or maybe I did something wrong with my Mongoose query ?

Comment: Based on the gigantic difference in time, it must be sorting before filtering, and your query is sorting the smaller filtered data set, just a guess

Comment: you could do a test, switch the order of the sort and the limit *(first sort, then limit)* If the duration stays the same you know that it is sorting before limiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `@JuanMendes` said in the comment, the first one does `sort` and then apply `limit`, which means MongoDB sorts all billions of documents and returns you 24 documents. In the second one, you are getting only 24 documents from MongoDB and sorting them using `javascript`'s sort. So the difference is not between native javascript sorting and MongoDB sorting. The difference is between sorting 24 documents and sorting billions of documents

The order of `sort` and `limit` does not matter. MongoDB always does `sort` before applying `limit`. See [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#combine-cursor-methods)

Comment: Ok so this is a normal behavior. But 10000 MS to sort it's really slow.  I thought than MongoDB got better performance. And I have an index on my datetime field

Comment: Are you having a single index on `datetime` or is it a part of a compound index?

Comment: `datetime    : {type: Date, index: true},`

Comment: Sorry, I was a little fuzzy on the details. You want the result to be sorted in ascending order not descending. So you did what you had to. Indexes sort document as they enter DB or at the time of index creation. They won't sort at the time you query. So, `sort and return` or `just return` both should take the same time. Can you once make sure that index created on that field and indexing is already complete, and background indexing is not happening at the time of your querying?

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your filter. Please check the performance issues with `$nearSphere` and test the query once without any filter

Comment: Without the $nearSphere I have a good performance on the sort. The couple sort + $nearSphere give a slow result. But I really need nearSphere

Comment: That should be a hard decision to make :)

Comment: But I can keep the javascript sort

Comment: Both may give you different results. They are not equivalent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137154/discussion-between-john-and-rar).